# 20 hour layover at London Heathrow. Do I need a transit visa to go to a hotel outside airport ?

Tags: visas, uk, transit, indian-citizens

I am an Indian national(Indian passport) traveling from Bangalore to US with a student F-1 visa. I have a 20 hour layover at London Heathrow. I will arrive at 1pm in LHR and leave for US the next day at 9:30am and I plan to stay at a hotel outside the airport during this time to get some sleep. So will I get the transit without visa(TWOV) for my case ? Also, will I be able to do some sighseeing while going to the hotel ? 
In any case, will I be denied to get out of the airport and stay at a hotel ?

Answer (score 1):

First, the airside parts of Heathrow close over night. So you will have to leave the airport via immigration whether or not you want to.

In your circumstance (Indian passport, holding a valid entry visa to the USA), you will be permitted to enter the United Kingdom for transit purposes providing you leave again the next day.

You do not need a visa, but you do need proof of your onward travel. A printed copy of your itinerary should suffice.

Here is the official information:

```
Visa required, except for Passengers holding confirmed onward
tickets passing through United Kingdom immigration to make a
landside transit to a third country on a flight that departs
before 23:59 the next day. The following conditions must be
complied with:
- passenger must arrive and depart by air; and
- passenger must have no purpose in entering the United
Kingdom other than to pass through in transit; and
- passenger must hold all documents required for the next
destination; and
- passenger must pass through United Kingdom Immigration; and
- passenger travels with a document listed in the following
warning(s):
- ***Warning*** Passengers may make a landside transit if
holding a valid visa which allows entry into Australia,
Canada, New Zealand or USA and traveling as part of a
journey to, from or transit through the country that has
issued the visa.
```

Once you have entered the UK you are free to go to your hotel and do some sightseeing, providing you leave before 23:59 the next day.